# Disconnect Google Account From Stackoverflow, Automatically Reconnects?

Tags: support, linked-accounts

I have two google accounts attached to my stackoverflow account.

I want to remove one of them (my brothers email) and let him create his own account.

So I used `my logins > remove this credential from your account`

However, when he signs in with his email, it just re-associates his email with my account and logs him in as the currently shared account.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is he logging in from a different computer? Did he log out first?

Comment: Same computer, yes we have tried logging out first and also during.  Different chrome profile, we have also tried using the Private Browsing thing in Chrome, whatever its called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider having him sign up for a new stack exchange openid account at https://openid.stackexchange.com/ and using that as his ID to sign up for his own Stack Overflow account.

Once that is established, he should be able to attach his google ID as well.

Comment: We will try that now.

Comment: It appears to have worked.  Thanks!